# Onexit.c error in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

When i try and run my program in release mode it goes straigth to

> Unhandled exception at 0x6f2426ef (msvcr100.dll) in FPS Game.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x12817c19.
>
> this is in the  static _onexit_t __cdecl _dllonexit_nolock function in
>   onxit.c on line 325 : *((*pend)++) = (_PVFV)func;

and i dont know why i have tried many things i cant get it too work i have sdl linked to my application if thats the reason but i really need help with this.

This is the code which is going wrong its microsofts :

```
static _onexit_t __cdecl _dllonexit_nolock (
        _onexit_t func,
        _PVFV ** pbegin,
        _PVFV ** pend
        )
{
        _PVFV   *p=NULL;
        size_t oldsize;

        /*
         * First, make sure the table has room for a new entry
         */
        if ( (oldsize = _msize_crt(*pbegin)) <= (size_t)((char *)(*pend) -
            (char *)(*pbegin)) )
        {
            /*
             * not enough room, try to grow the table
             */
            size_t grow=__min(oldsize, MAXINCR * sizeof(_PVFV));
            if((_HEAP_MAXREQ-grow<oldsize) ||
                ((p = (_PVFV *)_realloc_crt((*pbegin), oldsize + grow)) == NULL))
            {
                /*
                 * failed, try to grow by ONEXITTBLINCR
                 */
                grow=MININCR * sizeof(_PVFV);
                if ( (_HEAP_MAXREQ-grow<oldsize) ||
                    ((p = (_PVFV *)_realloc_crt((*pbegin), oldsize + grow)) == NULL ))
                {
                    /*
                     * failed again. don't do anything rash, just fail
                     */
                    return NULL;
                }
            }

            /*
             * update (*pend) and (*pbegin)
             */
            (*pend) = p + ((*pend) - (*pbegin));
            (*pbegin) = p;
        }

        /*
         * Put the new entry into the table and update the end-of-table
         * pointer.
         */
         *((*pend)++) = (_PVFV)func;

        return func;

}
```

Comment: Hard to help without seeing a line of code. Do you have global or static variables with complex initialization in your program?

Comment: yes i do its an FPS Game and it uses sdl so yes

Comment: No idea what SDL is, but if your program is crashing immediately then the likely cause is a bug in one of the constructors for one of your global variables. Or maybe it's a case of 'the static order initialization fiasco' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035422/static-initialization-order-fiasco but as I said just guesses with seeing any code.

Comment: sdl is a graphics library for c++ and its got a dll the error is not within my code its in the onexit.c which is a part of the librarys which happends to be in my application i put a break point in my main file int main(int argc,char** argv){
 game g;
 g.start();
 return 0;
} but it crashes before any of that happens

Comment: Q: Are you using Visual Studio for your C/C++ Compiler?  It sounds like the problem might be in some static class (which will be loaded before you hit "main()".  Regardless of your compiler/IDE, you *should* be able to get some kind of stack traceback...  Q: are either "pend" or "func" anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes i am using visual studio and no i have not used pend or func in any of my code

Comment: @Mac, just because the crash is in Microsoft's library code does *not* mean that the error is in their code. With almost 100% certainty I would say the error is in your code or your build procedures.

Comment: ok i wasnt blaming it all on microsoft but i happens in all my projects that have dlls linked so i think its some sort of error in the compiler or the code my code compiles normaly in mingw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on many years of experience and many similar experiences one of my rules of thumb is "No you haven't just found a bug in the compiler".

Firstly build the release with debug info - this should at least let you see the stack and maybe give you a clue what's going wrong.

Often this sort of problem is caused by

- using the wrong linker settings, or libraries (this is unique to MSVC
  / windows)
- linking against a release library that isn't built with
  the same code generation options;
- not initializing variables correctly (which often doesn't show up in debug mode)
- Not having consistent compilation options across all of the projects

Comment: thank you il go and have a look and also il try and compile it with code blocks which should work and il also try and have a look at the stack