# Is it possible to initialize a static member variable after running the main?

Tags: c++, static

Test.h

```
class Test
{
    static int i;
};
```

Test.cpp

```
int Test::i = 1;
```

I know that normally we initialize a static member as above. And the static member is initialized before the function `main` runs.
My question is:
Is it possible to initialize the static member **after** the function `main` runs? Something like this:

```
int main()
{
// do something
// initialize the Test::i here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to *initialize* it, but there should be no reason why you can't just call a static setter function that assigns a value to `i` in run-time. This is the best method.

Or you alternatively, you could make it so that the constructor always initializes the variable:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
  private:
    static int i;

  public:
    Test()
    {
      i=2;
    }

    void print_i (void)
    {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int Test::i = 1;


int main()
{
  Test test;

  test.print_i(); // will print 2
}
```

Comment: OK. I know what you mean. Btw, you can't initialize the static member in the constructor. :D

Comment: @Thomas It is not initialization, it is run-time assignment. Initialization would have been `Test() :i(2) {}` which will indeed not work.

Comment: oh. Sorry I misunderstand. You do "assignment" in the constructor, not initialization.  OK, got you.

Comment: @Thomas Note however that the above will cause problems if you declare an object to the class static/global. So it is not ideal. The best solution is to use a setter function.

Comment: While "it isn't possible to initialize it" is true when taken literally I think Wintermute provided an as-if solution which effectively does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you really mean initialization, so that assignment after `main` has started is out. This will not make a difference for basic types like `int` or `double`, but may make one for complex data types.

The answer is: no but yes (sort of). It is not possible to delay the initialisation of a static data member until after `main` started, but you can use a static member function with a function-local static object to simulate the effect. This object will be initialized after the function is first called. In code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() {
    std::cout << "A::A()\n";
  }

  void do_something() {
    std::cout << "A::do_something()\n";
  }
};

struct B {
  static A &a() {
    static A instance;
    return instance;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "main start\n";

  B::a().do_something();
  B::a().do_something();

  std::cout << "main end\n";
}
```

This will print

```
main start
A::A()
A::do_something()
A::do_something()
main end
```

You would then use `B::a()` where you'd have used `B::a` before. You will have to make sure that the function is not called before `main` is started.

Comment: Clearly the proper answer. Good observation that initialization time will only make a difference with types whose ctors have side effects or are costly. And the proper solution provided with it.

Comment: And why would anybody downvote this answer? (This is no complaint but an rfc.)

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake you have is that the variable 'i' is private for the class, so you cannot access it outside the class. There are two ways to fix this. The first is to make it public(not preffered) and the second to make setter and getter methods.

About the question the answer is yes, you can. Use the setter method I mentioned above. 
These are the two methods:

```
//…
public:
  static int get_i() {
    return i;
  }
  static void set_i(int val) {
    i = val;
  }
//…
```

You can call the method like that:

```
Test::set_i(10);
```

Note: do not forget to include the keyword `public` before the methods so you can access them outside the class.

Comment: I don't think he was trying to access it. He is only asking for initialization which is not related with access modifiers. I don't think your getter is initializing the variable. You are only reassigning the new value to i.

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing the word `static` and the word `const.`

You **have to** initialize a `const` when you declare it;

You **don't have to** initialize a `static` when you declare it, but you can change it anywhere anytime, given you can access it. (which is not the case here, your i is private.)

About thoses statements, let's look at the C++ standard (**3.6.2**) :

> Variables with static storage duration or thread storage duration
>   shall be zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place.

Technically, yes, your static data is always zero-initialized even if you explicitely initialize it.

Comment: If you don't initialize the static explicitly, it will however still get initialized to zero, which is required by the standard. There's no way to dodge where the static initialization takes place: it is always done before main() is executed.

Comment: @Lundin I don't agree, even if you initialize your static explicitely it still gets zero-initalized; but i've made my answer more clearer to illustrate why..

Comment: As usual downvoters, if you feeli like something should be improved, take a sec' and explain what.

Comment: (I didn't down vote)  No, if you initialize your static explicitly it gets initialized to that value and gets allocated in the `.data` segment. If you don't initialize it explicitly, it gets initialized to zero and gets allocated in the `.bss` segment. The text you quote merely means that static initialization occurs before what the standard calls "dynamic initialization".

Comment: @Lundi according to the C++ Standard, static data gets **always** zero-initalized, no matter what happens after.

Comment: `Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place. Zero-initialization and initialization with a constant expression are collectively called static
initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.`  This doesn't mean that the object gets initialized to zero first and then to something else, it just means that zero initialization occurs first in the order of initialization.

Comment: Or maybe it doesn't... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496795/example-static-and-dynamic-initialization. Whenever I assume that C++ behave in the same sane manner as C, the C++ standard proves me wrong.

Comment: @Lundin Yup, that's why i was asking myself how my answer could be improved, i don't know. But hey at least you learned somethin', so mission accomplished :D

Comment: Sometimes I think the only sane guy in the C++ standard committee who stood up on day one and said "but it doesn't make sense!" got executed right then and there, and then the merry work could continue and various substances could be smoked without protests.

Comment: @Lundin i mean i'm still trying to figure out why, don't get me wrong. Maybe there's that one scenario where you need to set before resetting ... Welp.