# Initialization of a static member inside a template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, explicit-instantiation

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
  B() { x = 42; }
  static int x;
};  

int B::x;

template <int N>
struct A {
  int foo() { return b.x; }
  static B b;
};

template<int N>
B A<N>::b;

//template struct A<2>; // explicit instantiation with N = 2 (!)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << A<1>().foo() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program writes 42 using g++ 4.9.2, but writes 0 using Visual Studio 2015 RC. Also, if I uncomment the explicit instantiation, VS2015RC also gives 42, which is quite interesting, as the template parameter here is different from the one used in the `main` function.

Is this a bug? I assume that g++ is correct, as there is a reference to `b` inside `foo`, so `B`'s constructor should be called.

---

EDIT: There is a simple workaround - if there is a non-static variable in `B`, that is referenced in `A`, VS2015RC will compile correctly:

```
// ...

struct B {
  B() { x = 42; }
  static int x;
  int y;                         // <- non-static variable
};

// ...

template <int N>
struct A {
  int foo() { b.y; return b.x; } // <- reference to b.y
  static B b;
};
```

This seems to work, even though `b.y`, as a statement, is obviously NOP.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035422/static-initialization-order-fiasco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [basic.start.init]:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place. A constant initializer for an object o is an expression that is a
>   constant expression, except that it may also invoke constexpr constructors for o and its subobjects even
>   if those objects are of non-literal class types. [ ... ]
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is
>   dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

In our case, `b` is statically initialized but `b.x` is dynamically initialized (the constructor isn't constexpr). But we also have:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
>   after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable
>   defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Odr-used means, from [basic.def.odr]:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used by ex unless applying
>   the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke any nontrivial
>   functions and, if [ ... ]

But evaluating `b.x` does not yield a constant expression, so we can stop there - `b.x` is *odr-used* by `A<N>::foo()`, which is also the first *odr-use*. So while the initialization does not have to occur before `main()`, it does have to occur before `foo()`. So if you get 0, that's a compiler error.

Answer (score -2):

I would be inclined to write the code like this:

```
struct B {
   B() {} 
   static int x;
};

int B::x = 42;
```

After all, the static (x) is defined (and therefore should be initialized) on the last line. Putting the initialization inside the constructor of B means that the static x (there is only one of them!) would be re-initialized each and every single time you construct a B. There is one static, you should initialize only once.

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: The bug is in the poster's code. Completely unwise to initialize a static repeatedly in the constructor.

Comment: This is a minimal example. The real code I'm looking at has a complex initialization involving two static arrays and template metaprogramming. Also, the static is not initialized repeatedly, as there is only one instance of B.