# Crash in boost Xml_parser_write.hpp

Tags: visual-c++, boost, xml-parsing

Here is the uploaded image

[image]

i am getting on inconsistent crash in my project sometimes, same screen shot is uploaded.

Is there any thing to avoid crashes access violation memory , i am using boost version 1.64

Comment: please. no screenshots

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any thing to avoid crashes access violation memory , i am using boost version 1.64

Yes, avoid [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Undefined Behaviour can have many reasons:

- stale references (e.g. reference to objects whose lifetime ended, most likely because of scopes, dynamic allocations, or use of globals in destructors outside of main triggering the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035422/static-initialization-order-fiasco))
- data races (lack of thread synchronization)
- many other things (out of bounds addressing, null pointer dereference, illegal reinterpret/const casting, very specific things like calling members through null-pointer `this`, calling virtual methods inside constructor, etc. etc.)

If you want more specific help, or can't find it

- post a minimal, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem

  - http://sscce.org/
  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
- use a memory checker to detect your bug earlier